# Tkinter event not trigerred in all child windows.

Tags: python, events, tkinter, python-multithreading

in my code, the main window is emitting event signals, which are to be caught by the child windows, which will show the change in a label. But only the last child window catches the event signal, and changes it's label. what's wrong?

```
from Tkinter import *
from threading import Timer as tt

class main(Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        Tk.__init__(self)
        tt(.5,self.timedsig).start()
        for  i in range (5):
            child(self,i)

    def timedsig(self):
        self.event_generate("<<timedsig>>")
        tt(.5,self.timedsig).start()


class child(Toplevel):
    def __init__(self,master,num):
        Toplevel.__init__(self)
        self.title(str(num))
        self.num=num
        self.var=IntVar()
        self.var.set(0)
        Label(self,textvariable=self.var).pack()
        self.master=master
        self.master.bind("<<timedsig>>",self.changelabel)

    def changelabel(self,e):
        print  self.num,self.var.get()
        self.var.set(self.var.get()+1)


if __name__=="__main__":
    main().mainloop()
```

Comment: I think you can only bind a single function to an event so only the last bind for a given event is applicable.

Answer (score 1):

Calling `bind` also *un*binds all previous functions. To bind an additional function, you need to use the optional 3rd argument:

```
self.master.bind("<<timedsig>>",self.changelabel, '+')
```

But that's pretty silly to do in your case when you can simply pass the variable to the instances:

```
import Tkinter as tk

class Main(tk.Tk):
    def __init__(self):
        tk.Tk.__init__(self)
        self.var = tk.IntVar(value=0)
        for  i in range (5):
            Popup(self, i, self.var)
        self.timedsig() # start the looping

    def timedsig(self):
        self.var.set(self.var.get() + 1)
        self.after(500, self.timedsig) # call this again in 500 ms

class Popup(tk.Toplevel):
    def __init__(self, master, num, var):
        tk.Toplevel.__init__(self)
        self.title(str(num))
        lbl = tk.Label(self,textvariable=var)
        lbl.pack()

if __name__=="__main__":
    root = Main()
    root.mainloop()
```

Also, that's not what we usually call a "child". It's just a different object.

Comment: Actually i wanted to do update the screen in response to signal from parent window. using the third argument works! thanks a lot.